# Как реализовать быструю обработку файла, простым переносом данного файла на исполняющий скрипт

Tags: python, python-3.x, drag-n-drop

### Необходимо сделать вот так, как приведено в гифке ниже:

P.S. Я искал ответ на свой вопрос в drag-and-drop решениях, но ничего похожего я не находил.

[image: Пример]

Т.е. у меня есть файл. Он находится в какой-то папке.

Я его перетаскиваю на файл скрипта; скрипт активируется и возвращает (создаёт) конвертированный файл в той-же папке, где находится исходный файл или в папку по умолчанию (т.е. в самом скрипте указывается).

А также очень важно, чтобы скрипт работал и вручную (так же примерно приведено в гифке выше)

Comment: Просто проверяйте значение `sys.argv` в скрипте (вроде бы)

Comment: это по умолчанию уже работает (скрипт видит путь к файлу как `sys.argv[1]`)